# Omniatuh Devise Twitter Not sending user back to Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm following Ryan bates cast #225 devise and omniauth revised...once i click the link sign up with twitter it takes me to the

api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=vJQeSrxYa6gXSFUspRP9wuzgHTgGRDoN5YjenRGnDcU

page where it says Authorize batman-fansite to use your account? when i click SIGN IN nothing happens and I do not get sent back to my site and obviously not logging me in or signing me up.

the url changes to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate

but other than that nothing happens been working on this for hours now and followed every suggestion possible.....

please help

devise.rb

```
       config.omniauth :twitter, ENV["I PUT MY CONSUMER KEY HERE"], ENV["I PUT MY CONSUMER PASSWORD HERE"]
```

I also have an

omniauth.rb

```
         Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
             provider :twitter, 'I PUT MY CONSUMER KEY HERE', 'I PUT MY CONSUMER PASSWORD HERE'
         end
```

ive heard some suggestions that if you delete the omniauth.rb it will work since its already in your devise.rb but if i delete OMNIAUTH.RB i get a 301 Unathorized error and does not send me to the TWITTER SIGN IN PAGE......

if i get rid of the piece of code in devise.rb(not the whole file just the vonfig.omniauth part) and keep omniauth.rb I get a routing error

heres my

user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
     # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
     # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

     # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
     attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username

     validates_presence_of :username
     validates_uniqueness_of :username

     def self.from_omniauth(auth)
       where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.username = auth.info.nickname
     end
    end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
      if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
      user.attributes = params
      user.valid?
    end
  else
  super
end
end

def password_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end

def update_with_password(params, *options)
  if encrypted_password.blank?
  update_attributes(params, *options)
else
  super
end
end
end
```

my omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
 class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
 def all
   user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
   if user.persisted?
     flash.notice = "Signed in!"
    sign_in_and_redirect user
   else
     session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
   end
   alias_method :twitter, :all
  end
```

routes.rb

```
        devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}, 
          controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

in my gem file

```
gem 'omniauth-twitter', :github => 'arunagw/omniauth-twitter'
```

I've tried adding omniauth gem as well but that did not do anything

and in my views i have

```
  = link_to "Sign in with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter)
```

At twitter developer site I've registered my site added a callback url

and i made application type read and write...ive tried READ ONLY but that gets me a 401 error and Ive also tried READ WRITE AND ACCESS FIRECT MESSAGES but nothing works

only thing that send me to the actual twitter sign in page is if i check READ AND WRITE

If anyone has any suggestions PLEASE HELP

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set callback properly. if you are using localhost in your development then your callback should be

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback
```

You can also use IP address instead of localhost i.e. `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I've done that...localhost:3000 didnt work so i used ip address which worked......but i still get the same effect......I'm sure that my configurations at the twitter dev sites are accurate and that i added the correct consumer key and password.

Comment: Ok perhaps it may be problem in the code. We need need to figure it out.